# Bootstrap 2x2 Panels don't align when change width of browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have 4 panels, organised in a 2x2 format. 2 top panels are in a row class and each panel is in the col-md-6 class. Same for the bottom panels, as shown here:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <h2 id="panhd">Test 1</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <h2 id="panhd">Test 2</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <h2 id="panhd">Test 3</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <h2 id="panhd">Test 4</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I am getting is when I change the browser width, the panels go to this sort of layout:

```
     [P]
[P]
     [P]
[P]
```

Test 1 and Test 3 panel divs have the CSS `margin-left:50%` and **all** of the panel classes have the attributes `width:50%` and `padding-left:10px` this is just to make them look nicer.

How would I be able to have them go into the formation

```
[P]
[P]
[P]
[P]
```

When changing the browser width/viewing from mobile, instead of it becoming like this:

```
     [P]
[P]
     [P]
[P]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xs-12 and if the remove unuseful margin

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6  col-xs-12 text-center">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <h2 id="panhd">Test 1</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12  text-center">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <h2 id="panhd">Test 2</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6  col-xs-12  text-center">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <h2 id="panhd">Test 3</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <h2 id="panhd">Test 4</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this, and it seems like the margin-right which centres the left panels is the problem. Anyway to get around this? Thanks.

Comment: possible solution is wrap the 2x2 panel   md-6  inside a div of md-12 margin-auto (and remove the margin right for center le panel )